# Querying GPO Details

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, active-directory, group-policy

I need some help on querying GPO.

1. I want to know how many total GPOs applied for each OU.
2. GPO with out no parameters and no link
3. GPO's With less than 2 parameters and less than 2 links

Can any please help on this how to query these details in GPO. We have around 1000+ GPO's.

Regards,
Karthick V

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use some small `Powershell` scripts for this, mainly using :

- Get-ADOrganizationalUnit
- Get-GPO
- Get-GPOReport

From modules :

- ActiveDirectory
- grouppolicy

  ```
  import-module ActiveDirectory
  import-module grouppolicy
  ```

something like this :

> I want to know how many total GPOs applied for each OU.

```
$OUs = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -filter * -properties DistinguishedName,LinkedGroupPolicyObjects
foreach($OU in $OUs) {
   write-host $OU.DistinguishedName : $OU.LinkedGroupPolicyObjects.count
}
```

---

> GPO with out no parameters and no link

```
$GPOS = get-gpo -All | select-object DisplayName
foreach($GPO in $GPOS) {
   $myGPO = $GPO.DisplayName
   Get-GPOReport -Name "$myGPO" -ReportType Xml >tmp.xml
   [xml]$xmldata = get-content "tmp.xml"
   $computerLevel = $xmldata.GPO.Computer.ExtensionData | Measure-Object
   $userLevel = $xmldata.GPO.User.ExtensionData | Measure-Object
   $links = $xmldata.GPO.Linksto | Measure-Object

   $NbreLinks = $links.count
   $NbreComputerLevel = $computerLevel.Count
   $NbreUserLevel = $userLevel.count
   $totalParams = $NbreComputerLevel + $NbreUserLevel

   if (($totalParams -eq 0) -and ($NbreLinks -eq 0)) {
      write-host $myGPO
   }   
}
```

---

> GPO's With less than 2 parameters and less than 2 links

Just the same as above, but replace the `if` statement by :

```
if(($totalParams -lt 2) -and ($NbreLinks -lt 2)) {
   write-host $myGPO
}
```

---

- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617236.aspx
- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee461027.aspx